# Selected radio button, but need to refresh every 2 seconds for update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i am having this particular problem with jquery refresh and form, i need to make a form which refreshes every 2 second but yet keep the form selected with the inputs.

The situation is that its a timeslot radio form, so you're to select one option and if someone else selected that option earlier than you, the div will refresh and you will see the places being taken. Like a booking form.

Currently i have 1 div that calls to another page with get functions.

```
    var inputField;

    $("#dateslot").change(function(){
    inputField = $('#dateslot').val();
    });

    setInterval(getData,2000);
    getData();
    function getData(){
    if( inputField ) {
    $("#timeslot").load('burgerorder_check.php?dateselect='+inputField);
    };
    };
```

Comment: and are you having some trouble?  BTW what is face?

Comment: sorry no idea how that got in there ._.

Comment: why does you call getData() manually after doing the setInterval?  Also if you want it for 2 seconds then a setinterval of 1000 isn't going to work is it?

Comment: @Crays And what is your problem?

Comment: i needed to refresh the div yet keep the option selected, is that even possible @_@ ?

Comment: What you should do is: 
At the beginning of the function, check the current checked button. Then refresh, and at the end of the function, select the button again.
Then whenever the function runs, it won't keep the button checked, but will auto-check it again after the refreshment is over.

And about your previous comment, everything is possible.